# Print a Record in Landscape

Tags: ms-access, vba, printing, record

I have created a database, and now want to have a 'Print' button that allows the user to Print the current record selected, however, my database is layed out in Landscape format.

My question is how can I go about creating this button to print my record in Landscape mode? I've read a few places that you have to swap the Form into a Record before being able to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Access or something else as your programming language/environment?

Answer (score 1):

You said "I've read a few places that you have to swap the Form into a Record before being able to do this?" Actually you can just print the form if you like.  You can use this code:

```
Forms(Me.Form.Name).Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Form.Name, acPreview
```

Which will open a print preview of the current form.
Or if you really do want to print a record (not the form) you can do something like this:

```
Reports(me.CurrentRecord).Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
```

You can also use a string literal or variable in place of me.CurrentRecord.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy, just change the page orientation:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44150-printing-in-vbnet/

Comment: It doesn't seem this is really what I'm looking for, Are you sure this is the best method?

Comment: As far as I know you have 2 options:


1. Force the print to landscape using the link I sent you

2. Have the user choose landscape using the print dialog box


- As last resort you can try to force a specific page size:


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa169933(office.10).aspx